# Magento 2 admin split button actions

Tags: magento-2.1

I have created split button i.e. button with options as below.

1. Created block file

   ```
   namespace Yournamespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Product;

   class CustomActionList extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
   {

       /**
        * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context
        * @param array $data
        */
       public function __construct(
           \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,
           array $data = []
       ) {
           parent::__construct($context, $data);
       }

       protected function _prepareLayout()
       {
           $addButtonProps = [
               'id' => 'custom_action_list',
               'label' => __('Custom Action List'),
               'class' => 'add',
               'button_class' => '',
               'class_name' => 'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\SplitButton',
               'options' => $this->_getCustomActionListOptions(),
           ];
           $this->buttonList->add('add_new', $addButtonProps);

           return parent::_prepareLayout();
       }

       /**
        * Retrieve options for 'CustomActionList' split button
        *
        * @return array
        */
       protected function _getCustomActionListOptions()
       {
           /*list of button which you want to add*/
           $splitButtonOptions=[
           'action_1'=>['label'=>__('Action 1'),'onclick'=>'setLocation("ACTION CONTROLLER")'],
           'action_2'=>['label'=>__('Action 2'),'onclick'=>'setLocation("ACTION CONTROLLER")'],
           'action_3'=>['label'=>__('Action 3'),'onclick'=>'setLocation("ACTION CONTROLLER")']
           ];
           /* in above list you can also pass others attribute of buttons*/
           return $splitButtonOptions;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Created block file

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceContainer name="content">
               <!-- here we call our split button block   -->
               <block class="Yournamespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Product\CustomActionList" name="admin.product.customsplitbutton"/>
           </referenceContainer>
       </body>
   </page>
   ```

I am using this button in grid, beside Add New button [image].

But when I select items from grid and I click on button action, I am not getting selected row's data.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

**[vendor_name] / [module_name] /view/adminhtml/layout**

***yourLayoutFileName.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="[vendor_name]\ [module_name] \Block\Adminhtml\[LayouBlockFileName]" name="block_file_name"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

now create a block file

**[vendor_name]\ [module_name] \Block\Adminhtml**

**LayouBlockFileName.php**

```
<?php

namespace [vendor_name]\[module_name]\Block\Adminhtml;

class LayouBlockFileName extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
{
    protected $_template = 'blocklayouts/blocklayouts.phtml';

    public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context,array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->buttonList->add(
            '<Simple_button_name>',
            [
                'label' => __('Simple Button'),
                'class' => 'primary',
                'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'' . $this->getUrl('[route_name]/[controller_name]/[filename]') . '\')',
            ]
         );

        $addButtonProps = [
            'id' => '<Split_button_name>',
            'label' => __('SplitButton'),
            'class' => 'add',
            'button_class' => '',
            'class_name' => 'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\SplitButton',
            'options' => $this->_getAddButtonOptions(),
        ];

        $this->buttonList->add('<Split_Button_Name>', $addButtonProps);

        $this->setChild(
            'grid_filename',
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('[vendor_name]\[module_name]\Block\Adminhtml\[LayouBlockFileName]\Grid_filename', '[block_file_name]')
        );
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    protected function _getAddButtonOptions()
    {
        // you can pass multiple option here 

        $splitButtonOptions[] = [
            'label' => __('<splitButtonOptionName>'),
            'onclick' => "setLocation('" . $this->_getCreateUrl() . "')"
        ];

        return $splitButtonOptions;
    }

    protected function _getCreateUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl(
            '[route_name]/[controller_name]/[filename]'
        );
    }

    public function getGridHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('grid_filename');
    }

}
```

in above **grid_filename** is file where you creating an Column for grid  type your file name

now create a templet file

**[vendor_name][module_name]\Block\Adminhtml\templates\blocklayouts**

***blocklayouts.phtml***

```
<?php echo $block->getGridHtml() ?>
```

now run this command

```
php bin/magento set:up
php bin/magento c:f
```

now run your Admin Grid

***I Hope This Helps You.***